# What effect could prior illegal work in the UK have on future visa applications?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-bans

My groupmate was a student and was working illegally in London in 2016. In May, he was caught, taken by the police, released and allowed to leave the country voluntarily. According to his documents, he was not deported but banned from the UK  for 1 year.

Next May 2019, it is going to be 3 years. Is there any chance of getting a UK visa so that he is able to attend conference?

Comment: Anything's possible, but I think the chances of his application being granted are very poor, both because he didn't obey the rules last time and especially if he comes from a country whose residents are perceived by the UK immigration authorities as high-risk. He will have to show connections to his country (employment, salary, property, family) that will convince the UK authorities that, this time, he'll behave and leave when he promised. Without those, he'll be denied.

Comment: While he may not have been deported, he was under an administration removal order and, because he left voluntarily when given the order and didn't force deportation proceedings, the affect is the same. He violated visa conditions and would have to have significant reason to ask the UKVI to allow him to return. If not, a refusal could have a major and long lasting impact on his immigration record (for the UK and, potentially, other country's visa applications).

Comment: I'll also mention another hurdle: his working for a long time in the UK suggests that he cannot afford to pay for a trip to the UK and maintenance there. UKVI is likely to assess this factor alone as disqualifying.

Comment: Well he attend conference in USA and got japanese visa last year so do those help ?

Comment: For anyone in the circumstance of having been required to leave the UK, it is strongly recommended that they pursue any future visa applications with the assistance of an immigration lawyer. [The Law Society](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/) can help you find a UK immigration lawyer in your country.

Comment: Was he allowed to leave custody to collect his things before leaving the country?

Answer (score 3):

It might be possible but I do not think his chances are high.

The most important reason countries have visa systems is to keep out people who are likely to work illegally, and for that stay longer than allowed. Having been caught working illegally he has proven to be willing to break that rule.

The UK visa system does not block giving visa to people in his circumstances but it is not usual to ignore previous breaking of immigration laws.
Applying and being denied will hurt future visa applications, so better only try with the right kind of help. The law society https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/ can help you find the needed help.